# Bus error in my Implementation of std::lock

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to implement [`std::lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock). The strategy is to `try_lock()` each mutex, and if I fail, I unlock all the locked mutexes and start from the next mutex. I am getting `Bus Error: 10` when I run this code (not always though). I am unable to understand where I am going wrong.

Compiled with gcc and clang both - same result.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
int counter = 0;
std::mutex m1,m2,m3;

//base case
template <typename T>
void unlock_all(T& obj)
{
    obj.unlock();
}

// just keep unlocking!
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void unlock_all(T& obj, Args&... rest)
{
    obj.unlock();
    unlock_all(rest...);
}


template <typename T>
void unlock_last(T& obj)
{
    obj.unlock();
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void unlock_last(T& obj, Args&... rest)
{
    if(counter == sizeof...(rest))
    {
        unlock_all(rest...);
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        unlock_last(rest...);
    }

}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void lock_all(T& obj, Args&... rest)
{

    if(counter == (1 + sizeof...(rest)))
    {
        cout << "all locked!" << endl;
        //unlock all now
        unlock_all(rest...,obj);
        return;
    }

    if(obj.try_lock())
    {
        counter++;
        lock_all(rest...,obj);
    }
    else
    {
        // Here, if counter is NOT 0, we should unlock all the locks we have locked earlier and
        // try to lock from the next lock in line. We can use counter to find the 
        // locks that are locked.
        if(counter == 0)
        {
            lock_all(rest...,obj);
        }
        else
        {
            unlock_last(rest...);
            counter = 0;
        lock_all(rest...,obj);
        }
    }
}

void func1()
{
    m1.lock();
    cout << "THREAD 1 printing " << endl;
    m1.unlock();
}
void func2()
{
    m2.lock();
    cout << "THREAD 2 printing " << endl;
    m2.unlock();
}
void func3()
{
    m3.lock();
    cout << "THREAD 3 printing " << endl;
    m3.unlock();
}

void func()
{
    lock_all(m1,m2,m3);
}
int main()
{

    std::thread t1(func1);
    std::thread t2(func2);
    std::thread t3(func3);
    std::thread t4(func);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    t4.join();

}
```

Not really sure how to debug this. Code is pretty straightforward; what can I do here? Spent a few days on this and wasn't able to make any progress.

Comment: Add logging? Look at the core dump?

Comment: I don’t have a straight answer as I’m not an expert, but it looks like reading/changing counter without holding the lock might lead to race conditions if multiple threads try to lock_all simultaneously.

Comment: Try to change the type of `counter` to `std::atomic<int>` to prevent undefined behavior caused by data race.

Comment: This paper might interest you as it compares different implementations of `std::lock`: http://howardhinnant.github.io/dining_philosophers.html

Comment: @howard that’s where I read this! And the stable flavor is what I’m trying to implement here :)

Comment: If you would like to see how the "smart & polite" algorithm is implemented for a variadic list of locks, search for "libc++ git mirror" and inspect `<mutex>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variadic version of `unlock_last` always assumes that the first argument is not locked. Thus, in

```
        unlock_last(rest...);
        counter = 0;
        lock_all(rest...,obj);
```

If `counter == sizeof...(rest)` before you enter this (i.e., you've locked everything except the first argument to `lock_all`), then the call to `unlock_last` won't actually unlock everything you've locked.

(I hope that this is just a proof of concept, since mutable global state in a synchronization function is just...no.)

Comment: Thats it! Thanks! How did you figure this out? just reading the code?